# Lenstra's integer programming algorithm: Finding a lattice point “near the center”

Tags: lattices, norms, integer-programming

I have already posted this question on the [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591367/lenstras-integer-programming-algorithm-finding-a-lattice-point-near-the-cente) forum, but I suspect the question needs more detailed knowledge than most users have; please excuse the duplicate post. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Preliminaries**:
As part of Lenstra's algorithm for integer programming (see [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rudi/lecture8.pdf), page 4) we compute a linear transformation $\tau$ and a point $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ which meet certain conditions (step 1).
We then compute a reduced LLL-basis $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ for the lattice $\tau \mathbb{Z}^n$ (step 2).
In step 3, we need to find a point $v \in \tau \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $$\Vert v - z \Vert \leq \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n} \max_{i = 1, \ldots, n}{\Vert b_i \Vert}$$ where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes the euclidian norm.

**Claim**: The paper I'm working with claims that $$v = \lfloor \tau z \rfloor$$ (where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ is meant component-wise) meets the above condition. However, I cannot prove this claim.

**Work so far**: The linear transformation $\tau$ can be identified with the matrix $B^{-1} = (b_1 b_2 \ldots b_n)^{-1}$ where the basis vectors $b_i$ are taken as columns of $B$. So we can write
\begin{align}
\Vert v - z \Vert = \left\Vert \lfloor \tau z \rfloor - z \right\Vert
= \left\Vert \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{\left(\lfloor B^{-1}_{i\bullet} z \rfloor - z_i \right)} \right\Vert \enspace.
\end{align}
This is, however, of limited use (to me) as I do not have any knowledge about the structure of $B^{-1}$.
Possibly useful lemmata include Minkowski's inequality, the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality or any properties which follow from $b_1, \ldots, b_n$ being a reduced basis for $\tau \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Thanks in advance for any hints or ideas how to prove the claim.

**Further Work**:
Emil's comment lead me to try if
$$v = \tau \left\lfloor \tau^{-1} z \right\rfloor$$
has the required property.
Additionally, I replaced the floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ through rounding to the next integer $[ \cdot ]$ instead.

This leads to the following estimate:
\begin{align}
\Vert v - z\Vert &= \Vert \tau \left[ \tau^{-1} z \right] - z \Vert\\
&= \Vert \tau \left[ \tau^{-1} z \right] - \tau \tau^{-1} z \Vert\\
&\leq \Vert \tau \Vert \cdot \Vert \left[ \tau^{-1} z \right] - \tau^{-1} z \Vert\\
&\leq \Vert \tau \Vert \cdot \left\Vert \frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{matrix} \right)\right\Vert\\
&= \Vert \tau \Vert \cdot \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n}
\end{align}

It remains to be shown that
$$ \Vert \tau \Vert \leq \max_{i = 1, \ldots, n}\Vert b_i \Vert $$
holds.

Comment: Something's not right, as $v$ is not even in $\tau\mathbb Z$. Based on the given goals, I would guess the intended definition was $v=\tau\lfloor\tau^{-1}z\rfloor$. (And rounding to nearest should be better than floors.)

Comment: Thanks for your observation, Emil. I will try your suggestion for $v$.